# Adding branch policy reviewer only if other reviewer not approved

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to create this scenario in a branch policy:

Let's say we have two teams; Team A and Team B and current branch policy is that one member of each team is required to approve a pull request to this branch. This is our current setup.

Now, let's say we have two people; Andrew and Charles. Andrew is a member of Team A, Charles is not a member of either team.

What I want to happen is this; if Andrew approves as a Team A member then all is fine (assuming somebody from Team B also approves). If Andrew does not approve then somebody from Team A and somebody from Team B still need to approve but, in addition, Charlie also needs to approve.

Is that possible? I tried adding a new reviewer requirement consisting of Andrew and Charles. However, it appears that, if somebody from Team A (not Andrew) approves a pull request then both Andrew and Charles have to approve it in order for it to complete.

Answer (score 0):

No, it can't be done presently:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/381620/adding-branch-policy-reviewer-only-if-other-review.html